# How to POST values from a Drop Down List that is populated by values that are taken from a MYSQL server?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I was able to populate a drop down list using a MYSQL server and I now want to take that value, ideally in PHP, and capture it into a variable. The end goal is to use that variable and create an SQL query to run on the server. Thanks!

```
<select id="lstPropName" name="lstPropName">
    <option value=" ">Select Team Name</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TeamName from $TName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lstPropName = $row['TeamName']; 
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $lstPropName;?>"><?php echo $lstPropName;?></option>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>

</select>

$lstPropName = $_POST["lstPropName"];
```

Here is the complete code, it is inside a form tag:

https://github.com/SahasR/OpenSourceDebateTab/blob/10/01/2020Alpha/PersonalJob_Results.php

Comment: put the select into a form and use it for your query.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini it is inside a form tag I just didn't include that part here.

Comment: query can be run in another page? if yes just call action a form and use `$lstPropName = $_POST["lstPropName"];`